# Клонирование Object'ов с модификатором final

Tags: java, ооп

Будет ли `final` клон другого `final` объекта. Клонирование реализовано с помощю 
интерфейса `Clonable`.

Answer (score 1):

Если в классе копируемого объекта все поля final - да клонируемый объект будет неизменяемый.

```
class Original impl Clonable{
private final Object obj;

Original(Object obj){
     this.obj=obj;
}

Original clone(){
      return new Original(this.obj);
}
```

данный объект неизменяемый (все поля final) при копировании возвращается новый неизменяемый объект

---

Если вы про клонирование  объекта и будет ли переменная содержащая этот объект final, то все зависит от её объявления.

`final Object clone = original.clone();` - переменная объекта final

Comment: кмк автор имел в виду `final class Original``

Comment: @rjhdby класс помеченный словом final запрещен для наследования. В данном случае к объекту это имеет мало отношения. А автор спрашивал про объекты, тут сложно однозначно понять вопрос, поэтому написал 2 примера